# How can I convert (pass) an object that represents a two dimensional array to a 2-D array variable?

Tags: c#, object, multidimensional-array

In my C# code I have an object in my code that represents a two dimensional array. I tried to write the value to a file by just converting it to string. I got something like an array but I saw the data was truncated both in the rows and columns.

```
  var string = obj_1.ToString()
```

Then I could convert it to a 1-dimensional array with the following code:

```
  var string_arr = ((IEnumerable)obj_1).Cast<object>()
                               .Select(x => x == null ? x : x.ToString())
                               .ToArray();
```

But how can I convert this object to a 2-dimensional array? I have to pass all the elements of the object to the related variables.

My extended code looks like this: The object value e.Vqt.Value (from 3.party dll represents a string[m,n]

```
    public  void subscribe_OPC_items(string ip)
    {
        // Instantiate the client object.
        using (var client = new EasyDAClient())
        {
            client.ItemChanged += client_Main1_ItemChanged;                
            client.SubscribeMultipleItems(
                new[] {                           
                        new DAItemGroupArguments(ip, "OPC.IwSCP.1", "IndraMotion_MTX_P70,System.MessageStore,-1,1,-1,0", 1000, null),
                    });                
        }
    }

    public void client_Main1_ItemChanged(object sender, EasyDAItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Succeeded)
        {               
           
            var strings = ((IEnumerable)e.Vtq.Value).Cast<object>()
                               .Select(x => x == null ? x : x.ToString())
                               .ToArray();


        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is for serialization, why not use json and serialize to it?

Comment: please show how `ob_1` is defined. It's not entirely clear what you mean by "a two-dim array". Do you mean an `string[m][]` (an array of arrays), or a `string[m,n]` (a truely multi-dim array)?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain  I have updated my code accordingly

Comment: So, you have a `string[m,n]`, now what exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Flidor  I start this console app from a parent app with Process.Start. I want to send back the standard console output to the parent app. (I mean the object value)

Comment: So you need to serialize this to the Console? In what format? You can't just blurt arbitrary data to SdtOut ... how will the parent app understand what you are trying to send?

Comment: @Flidor  Sorry, forgotten to explain. I want to send it in this format becuase the output is very lightweight:  {{col1,col2,col3.};{col1,col2,col3};{col1,col2,col3}...} I will make this structure in the child code before sending to console output.

Comment: And communication via File or DB or some MessageQueue is off the table? It has to be Std-Out?

Comment: @I have choosen Std-Out because this was the easiest way for me. I tried with named pipes and some other methods, but as I am a beginner I couldn't make it. In reality I am a PLC programmer, I use  C# just for supplementary scripts like this.

Comment: if `e.Vtq.Value` is a `string[,]`, then you should be able to just use `Select(x => "{" + String.Join(',', x) + "}")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is something like `a1, a2, a3; b1, b2, b3`, i.e. using `;` to separate rows, and `,` to separate values, you could create a 'multidimensional' 2D array like:

```
var input = "a1, a2, a3; b1, b2, b3";
var jagged = input.Split(';').Select(row => row.Split(',')).ToArray();

var rowCount = jagged.Length;
var columnCount = jagged.First().Length;
var array2D = new string[rowCount, columnCount];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    var row = jagged[i];
    if (row.Length != columnCount) throw new InvalidOperationException("Inconsistent row length");
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        
        array2D[i, j] = row[j];
    }
}
```

As you can see, most of the complexity is in converting from a jagged (`arr[][]`) representation, to a rectangular 2D representation. This ignores any potential issue with escaping the separators, or handling the actual values.

Another approach is to use a 1D array to represent your 2D data. This can make serialization trivial, since most serialization libraries handle 1D arrays just fine. You just need to ensure at least the width is also included. Something like

```
public class MyArray2D<T>
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public T[] Array { get; set; }
    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get => Array[y * Width + x];
        set => Array[y * Width + x] = value;
    }
}
```

Note that error checking, constructors, etc have been omitted for simplicity.